# Installing OpenJDK 16 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, java

I am trying to install OpenJDK 16 on my Raspberry Pi 4. I'm running a minecraft server and there was an update recently which requires Java 16, but I have Java 8 installed. There  is no `openjdk-16-jdk` package so I downloaded the [tar file](http://jdk.java.net/16/) for `Linux / AArch64` as the Pi has an ARM processor. I then followed [these](https://chemaxon.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/43000529309-how-to-install-an-openjdk-tarball-on-linux-) instructions to install it. When I try to run `java -version`, I get this error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

It appears this is the wrong version, but neither of the Linux downloads on the website worked, so I'm not sure what is wrong.
Here's a bit of system information in case it's useful:
`Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7l+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:33:35 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux` 
And these are the options for `sudo update-alternatives --config java`:

```
Selection    Path                                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.16.0-openjdk-armhf/bin/java   1131      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.16.0-openjdk-armhf/bin/java   1131      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-armhf/bin/java    1131      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/bin/java    1081      manual mode
```

Comment: `AArch64` is 64-bit, your kernel is `armv7l` which is 32-bit. You cannot run 64-bit userspace applications using a 32-bit operating system. You'll either have to upgrade to a 64-bit OS, or find a 32-bit version of Java.

Comment: @tttapa Thank you, unfortunately it looks like all the downloads are 64 bit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrestled with the same issue a few days ago.

I have been running a Minecraft server on a Raspberry Pi 4, using Java 8, installed via `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`.

However, as of [snapshot 21w19a](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Java_Edition_21w19a), which was [a few snapshots before the 1.17 release](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Java_Edition_version_history/Development_versions#1.17), Java 16 has become the minimum for Minecraft.

The Java 16 binary in the `openjdk-16.0.1_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz` file I downloaded from http://jdk.java.net/16/ gives an error when run on my Raspberry Pi 4:

```
$ ./jdk-16.0.1/bin/java --version
-bash: ./jdk-16.0.1/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

If we use `file` on that binary, we can see a bit more detail:

```
$ file ./jdk-16.0.1/bin/java
./jdk-16.0.1/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64,
version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1,
for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, not stripped
```

Note "64-bit" and "ARM aarch64".

Compare this with the working Java 8 binary I have - note "32-bit" here:

```
$ file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/bin/java: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM,
EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3,
for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=6d2781f51a497603976e8fee28b888bd771fd5b7, stripped
```

I believe (I'm no expert) that the Raspberry Pi 4 CPU is able to run `aarch64` code, but the current default OS doesn't support it.

```
$ uname -a
Linux [name] 5.10.17-v7l+ #1414 SMP Fri Apr 30 13:20:47 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

There, note `armv7l`.

This article - ["How to Make Your Raspberry Pi 4 Faster with a 64 Bit Kernel"](https://medium.com/for-linux-users/how-to-make-your-raspberry-pi-4-faster-with-a-64-bit-kernel-77028c47d653) helped me to understand a little more.  If I read that right, although we could edit `/boot/config.txt` to include the `arm_64bit=1`, that would give us a 64 bit kernel, but not the ability to run 64 bit `aarch64` binaries, because we still have a 32 bit userland.  (If I've misunderstood here, I'd appreciate if someone could correct me so I can learn.)

So, summary so far: Oracle supply a Java 16 JDK at jdk.java.net, but the only ARM binary there is `aarch64`.  I think this may be supported by the processor on the Raspberry Pi 4, but not by the default OS.

Luckily, AdoptOpenJDK (run by [a community of Java User Group members, including some big names](https://adoptopenjdk.net/about.html)) seem to make a wider variety of Java binaries available for download.

I went to https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html and made the following choices:

- Version: **OpenJDK 16 (Latest)**

  - Chose because Java 16 is the minimum for Minecraft 1.17 (see top of post).
  - Note this isn't a "Long Term Support" (LTS) version. This Minecraft [Paper server post about Java 16](https://papermc.io/forums/t/java-16-mc-1-17-and-paper/5615) explains more.
- JVM: **HotSpot**

  - The alternative option here is OpenJ9, but I believe that Mojang ship and test Minecraft with the HotSpot JVM, so that's what I chose.
- Operating System: **Linux**
- Architecture: **arm32**

  - Not `aarch64`: see above
- JDK or JRE: **JRE**

  - To run Minecraft, all we need is a `java` binary. So the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is fine. The Java Development Kit (JDK) includes more tools, but the JRE is a smaller download and installation, so I went for that. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre) for more on JDK vs JRE.

Those choices have given me a working Java 16:

```
$ ./jdk-16.0.1+9-jre/bin/java -version
openjdk version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9 (build 16.0.1+9)
OpenJDK Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9 (build 16.0.1+9, mixed mode)
$ file ./jdk-16.0.1+9-jre/bin/java
./jdk-16.0.1+9-jre/bin/java: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0,
not stripped
```

... and this is working so far for me, in the limited testing I've done so far, with the vanilla 1.17 server JAR I downloaded from https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unlike mine it actually explains the process well so I've accepted it.

Comment: Thanks @Henry! It's not a perfect answer - there's still much here that I don't understand. Perhaps someone will improve it. I thought your question was well written, by the way.

Comment: Great answer @Ashley I just wanted to point out that, after download the `tar gz` file, you will need to extract it and bind the folder in the `PATH` environment variable with `export PATH=$PWD/jdk-16.0.1+9-jre/bin:$PATH`

Comment: the new link from where to download openjdk is [here](https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk17&jvmVariant=hotspot)
you would need 17.x for minecraft 1.18 and newer

Comment: Great answer - I messed around with `apt` for about 4 hours before I found this. In a few minutes, I was up running.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it worked for me (To install openjdk 16 for minecraft 1.17.1):

First I downloaded any jdk by using:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Then I downloaded [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E328cfdqECZfIO8vGW0nL0DeBe8ZKQh4/view?usp=sharing) and extracted it in a new folder under /usr/lib/jvm

After that I runned:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/{name of the folder you just created}/bin/java 1131
```

And then I checked it was installed and selected by using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the JDK was 64-bit and the Pi is 32-bit, I had to get a 64-bit terminal by following [this guide](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=269515#p1635236) and doing the following:

1. `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get -y upgrade` to make sure everything is up to date
2. `sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends raspbian-nspawn-64` to install the 64-bit Debian Buster terminal
3. `ds64-shell` to launch the 64-bit shell
4. I used [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436618/7519434) to install java 8 in the 64-bit shell. From there I followed the same procedure as before to install java 16 and it worked.